# Ordered Lists and Lists in responsive web design

Tags: responsive-design

I am new to responsive web design and I am not sure why the ordered list and list is not responsive like the rest of the page.

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

ol {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica; 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 500px;
  text-decoration: none;  
}


li {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica; 
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: green;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Step 1: Choose Your Drink</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Chai Latte</li> 
    <li>Americano</li>
    <li>Pumpkin Spice Latte</li>
    <li>Vanilla Bean Frappuccino</li>
  </ol>

  <h2>Step 2: Join Us! and receive daily drink recipes.</h2>
</div>
```

any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ol{margin-left: 500px} is the culprit.

Try the following changes

```
ol{
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: green;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

I don't think this was exactly what you were looking for, but it should get you closer